# incorrect urls (leading slash '/') in 'href' and 'src' in links and scripts in index.html (build from nextjs)

Tags: javascript, html, next.js, deployment, build

when I build and export my nextjs app I find the index.html file lacks css and js pages, the links for these pages has a leading slash '/' that I usually manually remove to activate the css and js pages example:

```
<head>
    <meta charSet="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="preload" as="font" href="/_next/static/media/c9a5bc6a7c948fb0-s.p.woff2" crossorigin=""
        type="font/woff2" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/_next/static/css/e7d3bab42d******.css" data-precedence="next" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/_next/static/css/6a89e14abc******.css" data-precedence="next" />
    <link rel="preload" href="/_next/static/chunks/webpack-9265c03c2c******.js" as="script" fetchPriority="low" />
    <script src="/_next/static/chunks/fd9d1056-3d99af6b23******.js" async=""></script>
```

I removed some of the file name for security reasons (beginner in web security don't judge)
as shown above after the href or src there is a slash `href="/` that I remove manually
to be `href="_next..."`
how can I let next solve this for me (I want to automate deploying)

the deployment is linked to my github repo and it runs a script `npm run build`

this is part of my *package.json*

```
"scripts": {
"dev": "next dev",
"build": "next build && next export",
"start": "next start",
"lint": "next lint", },
```

Comment: _Why_ do you remove them? These slashes are correct and _should_ be there, if its not working without removing them, you're doing something wrong. How do you deploy this site?

Comment: I will edit my question and put how I deploy

Comment: In addition to what @tkausl has said. Manually processing your files should be the first step to knowing that you are already doing something wrong. [NextJS can potentially generate 1000 files](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/deploying/static-exports#deploying) like these. What will you do? Manually process these?